# How do I access information from another android applications widget?

Tags: android, widget

I want to get the string that is displayed on a widget, this string is displayed in a notification when the phone has the screen off. How would I go about getting that information in the background with my application? I am trying to make an app that allows someone to switch accounts easier for a computer application.

Comment: Currently, I'm not certain this is possible if I'm understanding you correctly. Are you asking to grab the text on a widget from another app?

Comment: yes, that is correct